# Verb conjugation convergence

Tags: verbs, conjugation

Portuguese has a strange coincidence in the preterit perfect tense of the verbs *ir* (to go) and *ser* (to be): they are conjugated exactly equally.

**Portuguese — English to go | English to be**

- Eu fui — I went | was
- Tu foste — You (singular) went | were
- Ele/Ela foi — He/She went | was
- Nós fomos — We went | were
- Vós fostes — You (formal / plural (outdated)) went | were
- Eles/Elas foram — They (masculine/feminine) went | were

What is the name of this verb conjugation convergence phenomenon? Do you know more examples of it occurring in any language?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you mean that the two verbs have exactly the same forms for this tense?

Comment: Same thing in Spanish. The preterite (old Latin perfect) forms of both _ser_ and _ir_ are: _fui, fuiste, fue, fuimos, fueron_. The perfect of _ire_ (_ii, iiste, ivit,_)  must have died out, and the perfect form of _esse_ (fui, fuiste, fuit,_) took over.

Comment: @curiousdannii: Yes, it is exactly that.

Comment: Come to think of it, the perfect root (_fu_-) of Latin _ire_ is itself suppletive, and appears also in the future progressive _futurus_ and, in a different ablaut grade, in the inchoative _fieri_ and subjunctive _fiat_. These come from the [PIE root *bheuə-](http://web.archive.org/web/20080726191329/http://www.bartleby.com/61/roots/IE62.html) 'to be, exist, grow', whereas the other forms of _sum_ come from the [PIE root *es-](http://web.archive.org/web/20080629082112/http://www.bartleby.com/61/roots/IE133.html) 'to be'. A bit of syncretism going on here already.

Comment: @jlawler: Thanks. Now I know that it was the *ire* verb conjugation that disappeared, and it was replaced by the *ser* one. What are your sources?

Comment: @sergiol: [AHDI-ER](http://web.archive.org/web/20080628053511/http://www.bartleby.com/61/IEroots.html), of course, OED, [Perseus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?redirect=true&lookup=io&author=*Roman&lang=Latin&corpus=Roman), and http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/wow/grammar.latin.html

Comment: @jlawler "in a different ablaut grade" -- not really; this PIE root appears only to have existed in the zero grade (*bhuH). Fio appears to be a derivative in -ye/o- (*bhUh-ye/o-).

Comment: @TKR Its ablaut patterns are certainly somewhat unusual and don’t seem to correspond exactly to anything else, but it seems unlikely that it **only** existed in the zero-grade, given the IIr. full-grade presents (Skt. _bhávati_, Av. _bauuaiti_) and OIr. o-grade preterite _boí_ (possibly un-reduplicated). It definitely had a predilection for zero-grade forms, but that doesn’t mean it was a monograde root.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Both those forms [have been explained](http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~jasanoff/pdf/Where%20does%20Skt.%20bha_vati%20come%20from_.pdf) (possibly wrongly, of course) as branch-specific innovations.

Comment: Other examples: Asturian has the *ser/dir* (to be/to go) overlap in preterite and derived forms, but also has *tar/tener* (to be/to have; *tuvi, tuvisti...*) sharing in preterite and derived. In the potential mood, *dir/dicir* (to go/to tell; *diré, dirás...*) also overlap.

Comment: @jlawler: If it came to Portuguese it would be: eu i, tu iste, ele iu, nós imos, vós istes, eles iram. And it is exactly equal to the perfect preterit for the **regular** verbs of the **3rd conjugation** (ex: eu parti, tu partiste, ele partiu, nós partimos, vós partistes, eles partiram). It is a pity it has not survived in this form; it would be much more **regular** and **distinct** from the **ser** verb's perfect past tense.

Answer (score 7):

Corbett calls this (in Spanish) **overlapping suppletion** in his [2007 paper](http://www.surrey.ac.uk/LIS/SMG/suppletion-Lg-PREPRINT.pdf) in Language. Stump is credited with the term **heteroclisis** (see [Maiden (2009)](http://webilc.ilc.cnr.it/~pirrelli/ESF_workshop/materiali/maiden/fulltext.pdf)).

Comment: "overlapping suppletion" could be translated to Portuguese with something as "Supletismo por sobreposição"

Answer (score 2):

Corbett's 2007 paper attributes the term "overlapping suppletion" to Juge (1999).
Juge, Matthew L. 1999. On the rise of suppletion in verbal paradigms. *Berkeley Linguistics Society* 25.183–94.

Answer (score 0):

Another example in another language (English):

English "go" and "wend" share the same past, although Dictionary.com & Amer. Heritage say the past of "wend" is now "wended", and "went" is archaic:

I went;
(thou wentest);
he/she/it went;
we went;
you went;
they went